# How can i get request parameters through ajax in js file?

Tags: javascript, ajax

> I have send the ajax request to the js file like below

```
 function add(lt,ln)

{

    $.ajax({

          type: 'get',
            url: "js/abc.js",
            data: {action: "addme", lt: lt,ln:ln},
            async: false,
            success: function(data){

            }
            });



}
```

> Now the question is  i need lt and ln variable in abc.js file. How can
>   i get these variable when this request is send i want n abc.js file

```
if(action==addme)
{
var lt=set value which is comng from ajax request.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it in JS file

After sending Ajax GET request, url will become `./js/abc.js?action=action&lt=lt`. Hence, you are sending parameters to JS file & JS file will not execute or change automatically because `.js` extension. except: when you changed server configuration

*Another way is:* to change your file extension to `.php` or `.html` or whatever(JavaScript output in PHP file)

Like:

```
function add(lt,ln)
{
    $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: "js/abc.php",
          data: {action: "addme", lt: lt,ln:ln},
          async: false,
          success: function(data){
           ///Do something with 'data'
           ///'data': var lt=lt; alert(lt);
            }
            });
}
```

**js/abc.php**:

```
<?php
   $action = $_GET["action"];
   if($action=="addme"){ //check if action=addme
      echo "var lt=".$_GET["lt"].";"; //Adding variable coming from Ajax request
    }?>
 alert(lt);
```

*Try to understand code. Hope it will help you*

Comment: What could we do with the lt var returned as string in data? Maybe an eval(data) ?